# What is the term for the idea that everyone should vote according to their own best interests?

Tags: voting, democracy, political-theory, terminology

What is the name for the theory that democracy should work like the more optimistic theories of [free market competition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laissez-faire), where (*ideally*) things work best when everyone votes narrowly according to their own best interests?

Comment: @user4012, All forms of government may err.  Showing that democracies are not infallible wouldn't be sufficient grounds for a condemnation of their general efforts, nor those of any fallible but striving voter.

Comment: @agc - my problem is with the fallacious assumption that (1) someone is somehow entitled to decide what is "in best interest" of someone else and (2) that it's even possible to determine that.

Comment: I keep re-reading this, but I don't think I understand the question. In a system with voting it is always assumed that people vote according to what they think is best, but "best" might not be narrowly defined. The title doesn't seem to match the body - what does voting for what is in your best interests have to do with democracy as competition. Its not clear what you mean by "things work". Its not clear if a democracy where people vote for something that ultimately harms themselves could be. Please edit to expand and explain, and give some context.

Comment: @user4012, Re "*...of someone else...*":  I don't this Q is about that.  It's about plumbers voting for what's good for plumbers, oilmen voing for what's good for oilmen, group X voting for what's good for Xs, more or less *oblivious* to the general interest.  The theory being that in the aggregate all these disparate groups voting that way actually arrive at the general interest enough of the time to keep the system viable.

Comment: @JamesK I don't support it, I just knew I have heard about it, so I don't know if they're _supposed to_ vote according to their best interests or if the system just counts with it. If you know about a similar idea that sounds like this, please come forward with it, the thing is - I don't know the theory, that's why I'm trying to know the actual context.

Comment: @user4012 I can't familirize myself with this theory in any form that comes to my mind as well, that's why I'm looking for the context. Philosophy always turns out to be more complicated.

Comment: @agc - that sounds like political version of Adam Smith's invisible hand, then

Comment: Why is this on hold? If you have any background in voting behavior, this is clearly asking about some fairly ordinary terminology. What piece of information would clear up what OP is asking for?

Comment: @JamesK - It is not always assumed that this is the case. There is a lot of research out there that suggests people vote for reasons other than their own self-benefit. Outside of academics, there are a lot of people who advocate voting for a social good, rather than what is in an individual's best interest.

Comment: [Related](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/which-portions-of-rural-metropolitan-voter-income-have-benefited-from-regional-v) - Part of the answer is already here.

Comment: Non-strategic voting?

Answer (score 7):

[Ethical egoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_egoism).  Ethical in this sense is saying that it is ethical to be an egoist, as opposed to being [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_egoism) to be an egoist or [inevitable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_egoism).

By contrast, altruism is the belief that it is ethical for people to try to do what is best for everyone else.

Comment: That'd be a general category, rather than a term specific to democratic systems.

Comment: @Probably Can you be a bit more specific about what you were looking for instead?

Comment: see @agc I'm looking for a politological theory.